# Show div based on another divs id value

Tags: jquery, smarty

I'm working with a shopping cart which loops through product option IDs in a db table. For each option it creates a label and select menu which are wrapped in a div who's ID value is unique to the option row id's it fetched from the db table. I'd like to be able to display a div with custom html above the option div wrapper if the wrapper ID value is == a specific ID.

Here is what a rendered div wrapper looks like which wraps the label and select menu

```
<div class="form-field product-list-field clear" id="opt_2_5">
```

The smarty code which generates this is here. You see the id=" part is where it's inserting the 2 and 5.

```
{foreach name="product_options" from=$product_options item="po"} 

   {assign var="selected_variant" value=""} 
   <div class="form-field{if !$capture_options_vs_qty} product-list-field{/if} clear" id="opt_{$obj_prefix}{$id}_{$po.option_id}">
```

If someone could help i'd like to write a condition similar to the below... (I totally made this if statement up and know it doesn't work. Any help would be really appreciated to make it work). I tried a smarty statement but i'm sure it can be done in jquery to display my custom div based on value == "opt_2_5" any help again is appreciated thanks

```
{if $id==2 && $po.option_id == 5 (Show div('#customIDofhiddendiv")}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the jQuery for you, but for `Show div('#customIDofhiddendiv")`, you can use the `display`/`visibility` attributes for your element to make it show up/disappear according to whatever conditions you want.  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I'm familiar with CSS and also $("#canvas-size").show(); or toggling based on an ID or '.class'. What I need help with is the if statement, not a css lesson.

Comment: If you are familiar with both those things I don't see why you can't put them together to write the `if` statement that you want.